# Replacing all functions with 'pass', syncing private to public github repo

Tags: python, libcst

I'd like to create a repository for a proprietary python module, similarly how this python package [mlfinlabs](https://github.com/hudson-and-thames/mlfinlab). They have emptied out all functions like this:

```py
    def bet_size_dynamic(current_pos, max_pos, market_price, forecast_price, cal_divergence=10, cal_bet_size=0.95,
                         func='sigmoid'):
        pass
    
    
    def bet_size_budget(events_t1, sides):   
        pass
```

I found the [libcst](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) module, that parses the source code and you can do operations on it.

Is there a better practice of doing this? eg.: github actions? I can't find any other good solution.

Comment: At this point it does not make any sense to use GitHub (or any other VCS). Just use a dedicated issue tracker

Comment: GitHub is preferred for various reasons, eg.: discoverability. The question more generally is how to run a script that empties out function and replaces them with pass.

Comment: Even if you insist of Github, what is the purpose of having all the code with just `pass`? Single landing page/readme.md and use the issues tracker of github.

Comment: Users can specify the location of the problem in the code and reference it in the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Github action to sync from private to public repo.
   Using this github action: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-repo-sync
2. `libcst` ([project site](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)) to strip functions afterwards (also as a github action step). Below is the codemod that you should put either

- in the libcst folder (`\Lib\site-packages\libcst\codemod\commands`)
- in your repo directory and then specify it `.libcst.codemod.yaml` (**this is needed if you run the codemod on github actions**):

```yaml
# String that LibCST should look for in code which indicates that the
# module is generated code.

generated_code_marker: '@generated'

# Command line and arguments for invoking a code formatter. Anything
# specified here must be capable of taking code via stdin and returning
# formatted code via stdout.

formatter: ['black', '-']

# List of regex patterns which LibCST will evaluate against filenames to
# determine if the module should be touched.

blacklist_patterns: ['.*replace_functions\.py']

# List of modules that contain codemods inside of them.

modules:

- 'libcst.codemod.commands'
- 'mycodemod' # THIS IS THE NAME OF THE FOLDER

# Absolute or relative path of the repository root, used for providing
# full-repo metadata. Relative paths should be specified with this file
# location as the base.

repo_root: '.'
```

put your codemod then under:

```
project_root
|--- mycodemod
         |--- __init__.py    (this is an empty file)
         |--- replace_functions.py (the codemod pasted below)
```

In `replace_functions.py` put this snippet:

```py
from ast import Expression, literal_eval
from typing import Union

import libcst as cst
from libcst.codemod import CodemodContext, VisitorBasedCodemodCommand
from libcst.codemod.visitors import AddImportsVisitor


class ReplaceFunctionCommand(VisitorBasedCodemodCommand):
    # Add a description so that future codemodders can see what this does.
    DESCRIPTION: str = "Replaces the body of a function with pass."

    def __init__(self, context: CodemodContext) -> None:
        # Initialize the base class with context, and save our args.
        print("this happens")
        super().__init__(context)


    def leave_FunctionDef(self, original_node: cst.FunctionDef, updated_node: cst.FunctionDef) -> cst.FunctionDef:
        replace_function = cst.FunctionDef(
            name=updated_node.name, 
            params=cst.Parameters(), 
            body= cst.SimpleStatementSuite((cst.Pass(),)), 
            returns=None)
        
        return replace_function
```